# Converting XLS(X) to csv with ssconvert or something else

Tags: xlsx, xls, rhel, gnumeric, ssconvert

I'm trying to convert XLS(X) files to csv on a RHEL server and have learned about gnumeric which includes ssconvert. I've done testing on a lab VM to make sure ssconvert works for what I need. However, I want to know if there is a way to install ssonvert by itself (with any libs/dependencies it needs) and not install everything else that comes with gnumeric.

Alternatively, is there another way to convert XLS(S) files to csv?

Comment: Have you looked at this? https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/10411/convert-csv-to-xlsx-from-console/, or maybe this: https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/2641/convert-to-command-line-parameter/

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to installing LibreOffice, you can accomplish this using:

`soffice --headless --convert-to csv yourfile.xlsx`

The output will be comma-separated, newline delimited (though you should test specific behavior on your system to be sure).